# powershell output multiple variables derived from processlist

Tags: powershell

I have the below bit of code, it is designed to simply ask for a Windows ProcessName, and then return a list of all instances of that process that are running.

```
$processName = Read-Host 'Please Enter the Process Name, as shown in Task Manager (not inc *32)'
if (!$processName) 
{ 
    "No Process Given"
}
else
{
    "You Entered "+$processName

    $filter = "name like '%"+$processName+"'"
    $result = Get-WmiObject win32_process -Filter $filter | select CommandLine

    $counter=1
    foreach($process in $result )
        {
            write-host "$counter) $process"
            $counter++
        }    
}
```

It works fine up until the point where it outputs the list.

If I do

```
echo $process
```

then I get what I am after e.g.

```
"C:\folder\AppName.exe"
"C:\folder\AppName.exe instance1"
```

If however I try to concatenate the `$counter` in front of it I get:

```
1) @{CommandLine="C:\folder\AppName.exe" }      
2) @{CommandLine="C:\folder\AppName.exe instance1" }
```

I've tried `write-host`, `write-output`, `echo`, various combinations of `""`, `+`, but I can't get rid of the `@{CommandLine= xxx }` when I try to combine it with another variable

Is there a way to get what I am after? e.g.:

```
1) "C:\folder\AppName.exe"
2) "C:\folder\AppName.exe instance1"
```

Comment: try `write-host "$counter) $($process.commandline)"`  OR modify your selection : `$result = Get-WmiObject win32_process -Filter $filter | select -expandproperty CommandLine` (note the -expand...)

Comment: cheers, both options worked. I'll go and read up on -expandproperty

Comment: i make a solution, so if you want to accept it, this question will not be flag as unanswered. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `write-host "$counter) $($process.commandline)"` 
OR modify your selection : 
`$result = Get-WmiObject win32_process -Filter $filter | select -expandproperty CommandLine`

explanation : without expandproperty you get a psobject with expandproperty you have a string

Comment: Cheers, that makes sense about it being an object or a string